# Return a result to the place where i navigated from with Mvvmcross 5 and Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have a problem with this sample from Mvvmcross5 documentation :

```html
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;
    public MyViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigation)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public async Task SomeMethod()
    {
        var result = await _navigationService.Navigate<NextViewModel, MyObject, MyReturnObject>(new MyObject());
        //Do something with the result MyReturnObject that you get back
    }
}

public class NextViewModel : MvxViewModel<MyObject, MyReturnObject>
{
    public async Task Initialize(MyObject parameter)
    {
        //Do something with parameter
    }

    public async Task SomeMethod()
    {
        await Close(new MyReturnObject());
    }
}
```

It seems to work with a simple Xamarin app with Mvvmcross project. Now, i need to use it with Xamarin.Forms : the close method is called but after showing the previous page, nothing happen :/

In output : "Requesting presentation change" maybe a clue ?